# Where is the Firebase Storage traffic statistics?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, traffic

Where are the Firebase Storage traffic statistics? I want to use Firebase Storage, but I don't know where are the traffic statistics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point of time you can't view Firebase Storage traffic statistics. Firebase team might be working on it for sure.